# Unicode converstion issue DMU in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle12c

Why are some fields still needing expanding after byte-to-char conversion?
e.g. If a field is varchar2(30 byte) before the conversion, then we convert byte-to-char and this field is now varchar2(30 char), why are some fields not being able to handle the data that was in there previously and now to be expanded to varchar2(30+x char)...